# How to save datetime-local value in text file on php?

Tags: php, datetime, input, fopen, fwrite

How can I **save a datetime-local input value into a text file on php?** I have studied [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524184/save-datetime-issue-with-users-local-datetime), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38094920/how-to-retrieve-the-value-from-datetime-local-input) with no success.

I am already doing it with text and email:

```
<?php {$text = $_REQUEST['text'];$email = $_REQUEST['email'];$datetime = $_REQUEST['datetime_local_input'];$body = "$email $text $datetime";$file = fopen("f.txt", "a");fwrite($file, "\n" . $body."\n");fclose($file);} ?>
```

I use a simple input:

```
<input class="dt" type="datetime-local" name="datetime_local_input" title="choose date and time" required />
```

Comment: What is your current result?

Comment: I tried to retrieve the datetime-local using something like $datetime = $_REQUEST['datetime_local_input'] with no results at all. I am successfully retrieving email and text of course. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think your input tag needs a name attribute.

Comment: @BrianMinton I followed your suggestion (into the above code also) with no results. Alternatives?

Comment: Thanks for putting it in the code.  It appears that the name you give the tag in html (`datetime`) doesn't match the php name (`$_REQUEST['datetime_local_input']`).  I'd suggest changing the name in the html to `name=datetime_local_input`.

Comment: First let me say thank you for your time and suggestions (updated above). Unfortunately it didn't retrieve any data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it eventually by creating a new form with `action=""`, `method="post"` and using the above php and html. That saves successfully the value in the .txt file. Thanks everyone! I guess less is more.